# Undefine a macro in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

How do I undefine a macro in Objective-C?

I have situation where a macro is defined automatically, but I want to undefine it manually.  How do I do this?

```
#ifdef macro_name
    ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#undef macro_name
```

is the directive of your dreams.